# WKWebView slow loading issue

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

In my code, I load a local HTML file, replace a bunch of placeholders with some other stuff previously obtained from the server (mainly the content of a Wordpress post) and load everything to a `WKWebView`:

```
[postWebView loadHTMLString:postHTML baseURL:baseURL];
```

The problem is that, when I do so, the content doesn't show up immediately, especially if the page contains a lot of images. It loads some of them – sometimes them all – and then appears. Leaving the page hanging, completely white. Why does this happen? Shouldn't it load the text and DOM elements and only after the rest? With `UIWebView` this wasn't happening.